# ¿Como hago doble click en algun elemento de html y que me direccione a una pagina nueva con javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

esto me sirve pero lo que me interesa es enlazar a una pagina en este caso un formulario, pero quisiera saber como se puede hacer en javascript dentro de la function de dblClick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("tr").dblclick(function(){
         alert("Se ha hecho doble click");
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo el ejemplo que deseas realizar con **JavaScript** puro, ya que el ser una tarea muy simple no veo la necesidad de hacerlo a través de JQuery

> Para lograr abrir la nueva página que deseas con puro JavaScript,
>   tanto para el ejemplo de JS o de JQuery usa el método
>   window.open('example.com') que abrirá una nueva pestaña del navegador
>   web que estes usando

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="clickme">abrir otra página</button>
<script>
    let btn = document.querySelector("#clickme")

    btn.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
      window.open("https://www.google.com.mx")
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Lo único que hago es obtener por su `ID` el button y mediante un
>   `handler` le indico que cuando se ejecute el evento `dblclick` y
>   finalmente por medio del objeto del navegador "window" accedo al
>   método open y en forma de cadena de texto le indico la URL de la
>   página web que abrirá

Si aún así lo necesitaras con **JQuery** aquí esta el ejemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="clickme">abrir otra página</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").dblclick(function(){
        window.open("https://www.google.com.mx")
        console.log(1)
      })
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Consulta el ejercicio desde este enlace

http://jsbin.com/labugocaqe/edit?html,console,output

Comment: gracias, soy nuevo en javascript vengo de java y c, y estoy aprendiendo de momento